# Всплывающее сообщение после добавления в БД

Tags: php

Добрый день, имеется форма на страницу 1.php, которая отправляет данные на обработку в 2.php
Если не все поля заполнены, echo "Вы заполнили не все поля". Надпись появляется на 2.php и перебрасывает автоматически на 1.php. Соответственно все заполненные поля обновляются. Как можно сделать, чтобы сообщение появлялось на странице 1.php и поля не обновлялись?

Answer (score 1):

Можно отказаться от файла 2.php. Для этого убираем атрибут action у формы, и тогда она будет отправлять данные в файл 1.php.
В файле 1.php добавляем проверку

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   //код сохранения в БД
}
```

Теперь с полями, как вариант сделать так:

```
<input type="text" name="my_input" value="<?= (isset($_REQUEST['my_input']) ? $_REQUES['my_input'] : '') ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

хочется картинкой ответить....

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а по правильному, форму должен javascript проверять.

Comment: Правильно проверять и там и там, причем в идеале критерии проверки должны быть написаны в одном месте и для фронта и для бэка